# How to modify a specific row of a csv line?

Tags: java, csv

testline: `1,,,,test,,asd,,`

I want to modify the 5th row and replace the word `test` with "xxx"`. The testword could be any value.

How could I best do this? Is there any apache-commons library that can give me back the index of the n-th occurence of the separator `,`? Then I could eg use something like:

```
sb.append(line.substring(0, theIdx))
  .append("xxx")
  .append(line.substring(theIdx+1));
```

But how could I get the n-th index of the separator in the line?

Comment: Why not simply use a Java CSV library?

Comment: Because intregrating additional libraries just for the purpose of a simple task is not the best solution, if most of the lib is not used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I found `StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf()` to be what I looked for.